# setHgap() method sets a vertical gap instead of horisontal

Tags: java, javafx, gridpane

I am just starting to learn JavaFX, and I have made a program to display three random domino tiles in a `GridPane`. I am just curious why the setHgap() method creates vertical lines instead of horisontal lines, and vice versa?

Code example and image below:

```
public class Chapter_14_E03_DisplayThreeTiles extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Application.launch(args);

    }

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Create an arraylist to store number values
        ArrayList<Integer> tileNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 36; i++)
            tileNumbers.add(i);
        java.util.Collections.shuffle(tileNumbers);

        // Create a pane to hold the images
        GridPane pane = new GridPane(); 
        pane.setHgap(2); // Creates horisontal lines ???

        // Add images to pane
        for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
            pane.add(new ImageView(new Image("file:image\\tiengow\\" + tileNumbers.get(i) + ".png")), i, 0);
        }

        // Create a scene and place it in the stage
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Exercise_14_03");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

}
```

Produces following output:

[image]

Comment: Horizontal gaps will look like vertical lines. The point is, it's adding an offset to the x position of each grid cell. i.e. a horizontal gap. It's working as intended.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense!